# regex capture lines before certain keywords that may or may not be present

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

```
Changeset: 8675309
User: DOMAIN\JohnG
Date: 01/21/2004 21:03:45
Comment:  This check-in fixes issues in several features.  I also refactored some items in buf.c into a new file named bif.c because buf.c was too hard to parse.
Items:
   $/baz/proj/bif.c           Added
   $/baz/proj/buf.c          Modified, Renamed
Work Items:
   34527     The "Access Denied" message is not descriptive enough.
   35628     The UI flickers when I press the '8', 'y', 'Ctrl', and 'End' buttons at the same time.
Check-in Notes:
   Code Reviewer:  ShellM
   Performance Reviewer: ShellM
   Security Reviewer: ShellM
```

I want to capture the two lines under Items. However Work Items may sometimes be missing, so Check-in Notes: would be where i stopped, and then sometimes BOTH would be missing so I would need to stop at the end of the string.

```
(?s)(?<=Items:).*(?(?=Work Items:)|(?=Check-in Notes:))
```

this is what I have and it captures everything UP TO check-in notes which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([\s\S]*\nItems:\n)([\s\S]*?)(\nWork Items:\n[\s\S]*)?\z
```

This seems to work. Your **items** should be placed in group 2.

1. `([\s\S]*\nItems:\n)` this tells the regex to start with "Items:"
2. `([\s\S]*?)` this means take characters, but a less as possible (non greedy)
3. `(\nWork Items:\n[\s\S]*)?\z` This tells the regex to fill the third group with "Work Items", if possible.

This leaves your second group with either

- everything from "Items:" to EOF, or
- everything from "Items:" to "Work Items:" (exclusive)

The keypoints are that the second group (your items) is **not greedy** and the third group is **optional**.  Meaning it will always try to match the third group, but fall back to take everything that remains.

### EDIT:

After trying this in .Net the regex above did not work. But with small adjustments (like allowing for Win and *nix style line endings) it worked.

```
var pattern = @"((\n|\r|\r\n)Items:(\n|\r|\r\n))(?<Items>[\s\S]*?)((\n |\r |\r\n)Work Items:(\n |\r |\r\n)[\s\S]*)?\z";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);

var match = regex.Match(YOUR_FILE_HERE);
var items = match.Groups["Items"].Value;
```

Comment: what about the times that Work Items: isnt present but Check-in Notes is

Comment: in my tests it worked. This is why the third group is optional.

Comment: i tested with a different site. But this version works for me https://regex101.com/r/B0naal/5 (i updated the answer)

Comment: I did test this in .Net. I had to adjust the regex a little, but now it works with trailing Work Items, and without. Will update the my answer.

Comment: i just copied your code and pasted it into a .net app and it captures WorkItems and Check-in Notes with the Items

Comment: if this solved your problem, please accept the answer to close this  thread

Comment: no im saying it doesnt solve it because it accpets workitems and checkin notes when i want to cut off at those points

Comment: look at the last section. The match group "Items" contains only your items. Wasn't your goal to extract the content of items?

Comment: yes, i literally copied and pasted your code and ran it with my text block and inside of the "Items" section was still the other 2 sections

Comment: http://rextester.com/NCMY40535 the regex seems to work? are you sure you use it correctly

Comment: It seems to work when i do not manually construct the string with \n characters, so thank you for that! in order to capture the comment/user/changeset would I just repeat the behavior and just change the words?

Comment: Yes this sould work for the others too. The problem with your manually constructed strings is, that int windows world lines do not end with "\n", but with "\r\n". Although i thought it should work there too...

Answer (score 0):

Try following which is tested

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication64
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static List<string> sections = null;
        public enum State
        {
            NONE = -1,
            CHANGESET = 0,
            USER,
            DATE,
            COMMENT,
            ITEMS,
            WORK_ITEMS,
            CHECK_IN_NOTES
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sections = new List<string>() { "Changeset", "User", "Date", "Comment", "Items", "Work Items", "Check-In Notes" }; 
            string pattern = "^(?'section'[^:]+)";
            string inputLine = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            State state = State.NONE; 
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                Match match = Regex.Match(inputLine, pattern);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    int index = sections.IndexOf(match.Groups["section"].Value);
                    if(index >= 0) state = (State)index;
                }

                switch(state)
                {
                    case State.COMMENT :
                        Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
                        break;
                    case State.ITEMS :
                        Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
                        break;
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this works the best of any so far, however, if they have "Items:" in their comment message then gives me that output as well